# Is ideal norm multiplicative in arbitrary order of number field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm wondering if is true that in any order $\mathcal{O}$ of a number field $K$ the ideal norm (defined by $N(I) = | \mathcal{O}/I|$ is multiplicative. I'm reading Cox's book *Prime numbers of the form* $x^2 +ny^2$ and he proves it for proper ideals of quadratic fields (i.e. ideals $I$ such that $\mathcal{O} = \{ \beta \in K | \beta I \subset I\}$) which happen to be the invertible ideals. His proof really seems to use all the hypotheses so my (mostly random though) guess would be that it is false (the multiplicativity) in general.

If it is indeed false is it for true for special classes of ideals like for example propers ideals in arbitrary number fields or invertible ideals etc...

Thanks

Comment: The norm is always multiplicative, at least for number-fields.

Comment: Do you have any reference ?

Comment: [Take Here as a start.](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Algebraic_Number_Fields.html?id=RT5R_29X69wC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Doesn't the proof just use the chinese remainder theorem for arbitrary rings with a few other general arguments? If so then I can't see why it wouldn't be multiplicative (to my knowledge nowhere in the proof do you actually use the maximal property of the ring of integers, just the fact that it is a ring inside a number field).

Comment: Ok so I guess I was troubled by the fact that Cox uses a proof specific to his case of interest and didn't think to look wether the proof of the $\mathcal{O}_K$ case (which I know) applied to arbitrary orders. Sorry ! I'll go verify that it is the case just to make sure and will tell you the result of my investigations.

Comment: Well it seems like it didn't work after all see Hurkyl's answer.

Comment: The reason why we can't transpose the proof that we use for arbitrary ring of integers is that in this proof you first show the result for maximal ideals and then you say that every ideal can be decomposed as a product of maximal ideals because $\mathcal{O}_K$ is dedekind which you can't do in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$ with $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $(1,3i)$. This is an order in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Let $I$ be the $R$-ideal $(3,3i)$ with norm $[R:I]=3$.  Note that $I$ is not a principal $R$-ideal.

We have $I^2 = (9,9i)$, which has norm $[R:I^2]=27$.

Now, $N(I) = 3$ and $N(I^2) = 27$, so the norm is not multiplicative.

The prime ideal $(3, 3i)$ is the only "singularity" of $R$. If $J$ is any ideal relatively prime to $(3,3i)$, then $N(J) = N(J \mathcal{O}_K)$, and so the norm is multiplicative on such ideals. A quick proof of this fact is:

$$ R / J \cong (R / J)[1/3] = R[1/3] / J = \mathcal{O}_K[1/3] / J = (\mathcal{O}_K / J)[1/3] = \mathcal{O}_K / J $$

However $\mathfrak{p} = (3, 3i)$ doesn't share a similar property; it "splits" into the principal prime ideal $(3) \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$; we have $R / \mathfrak{p} \cong \mathbb{F}_3$, but $\mathcal{O}_K / (3) \cong \mathbb{F}_9$.

Comment: A suggested edit substantially changed the mathematical comment of this answer. $I$ is quite deliberately the principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$ generated by $3i$, not the principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ generated by $3i$.

Comment: Quick question, why does $9i \in I^2 = (9)$? It seems to me that $9i$ should not be in $(9)$ since $i$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$, but I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: @MarcPaul: This has all fallen out of my head; is the previous version (which I've reverted to) to your liking?

Answer (score 8):

As Hurkyl mentioned, there are easy counterexamples. But one can say much more. Suppose that$\rm\,D\,$ is a *finite norm* domain, i.e. every ideal $\ne 0\,$ has finite norm $\rm\,|D/I|.\,$ Then it is easy to prove

- the norm is multiplicative for all nonzero ideals of $\rm\,D$ $\!\iff\!$ $\rm\,D\,$ is a Dedekind domain

Thus norm multiplicativity fails for finite norm domains that are not integrally closed, as in the example in Hurkyl's answer. For the simple proof, and a related criterion, see

Butts, H. S.; Wade, L. I. $\ $ [Two criteria for Dedekind domains.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2313916)
Amer. Math. Monthly  73, 1966, 14-21.

Answer (score 2):

Here a counterexample:

Let R be a number ring and $I\in R$ its ideal, I want to show that the norm of an ideal, defined as $[R:I]$ is not in general multiplicative. If we consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ and its ideal $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-19})$ we easily notice that : $I^2=2I=(4,2+2\sqrt{-19})$. Since $N(I)=\sharp\frac{R}{I}$, if we compute:
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]}{(2,1+\sqrt{-19})}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2,1+x,x^2+19)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]}{(1+x,x^2+1)}$$
And sending $x \to -1$ we get:
$$\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]}{(1+x,x^2+1)}\cong \mathbb{F}_{2}$$
Therefore, $N(I)=2$ and, if the norm is multiplicative, we should have $4=N(I)N(I)=N(I^2)=N(2I)=N(2)N(I)$ so what we need is to compute $N(2)$:
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]}{(2)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2,x^2+19)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x^2+1)}$$
Whose cardinality is 4 and then $N(2)N(I)=4\cdot 2\neq4$

The example of $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$ is wrong because $N((9))=81$ since:
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[3i]}{(9)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(9,x^2+9)}$$
But $(9,x^2+9)=(9,x^2)$ and so:
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(9,x^2)}\cong \frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{9\mathbb{Z}}}{x^2}$$

which has 81 element. Another way to see this is to consider:

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}\oplus (3i \mathbb{Z})}{9\mathbb{Z}\oplus (9\cdot 3i\mathbb{Z})}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{9\mathbb{Z}}\oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{9\mathbb{Z}}$$